# Grafana dashboard separating "boundedElastic" vs "parallel" for executor pool

Tags: java, spring-webflux, grafana, project-reactor

Small question regarding how to build Grafana dashboards which separates "boundedElastic" vs  "parallel" please.

Currently with a Spring Webflux app, I get out of the box very useful metrics for Reactor Core.

```
executor_pool_size_threads
executor_pool_core_threads
executor_pool_max_threads

etc
```

The Reactor Team even provides default dashboard so we can have visuals on the states:

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-monitoring-demo

Unfortunately, the current dashboards mix "boundedElastic" and  "parallel", I am trying to build the same dashboards, but with "boundedElastic" and  "parallel" separated.

I tried:

`sum(executor_pool_size_threads{_ws_="my_workspace"}) by (reactor_scheduler_id, boundedElastic)`

But no luck so far.
May I ask what is the correct way to do it please?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the demo project, the metrics are stored in Prometheus and are queried using [PromQL](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/). Each metric can have several labels and each label can have several values. The metrics can be selected by labels and values, e.g. `my_metric{first_label="first_value", second_label="another_value"}` selects `my_metric` where both labels are matching corresponding values.

So in your example the metric `executor_pool_size_threads` has the label `reactor_scheduler_id`. However, the values contain more information beyond scheduler name. On my machine (because of default pool size) the values are: `parallel(8,"parallel")` and `boundedElastic("boundedElastic",maxThreads=80,maxTaskQueuedPerThread=100000,ttl=60s)`. So regex-match is useful here for matching the values with `=~` operator.

PromQL query only for `parallel`:

```
sum (executor_pool_size_threads{reactor_scheduler_id=~"parallel.*"}) by (reactor_scheduler_id)
```

PromQL query only for `boundedElastic`:

```
sum (executor_pool_size_threads{reactor_scheduler_id=~"boundedElastic.*"}) by (reactor_scheduler_id)
```